# TypeScript: conditionally convert a set of types to a different set of types based on their names

Tags: typescript, types, casting, type-conversion, conditional-types

I've written my own TypeScript ORM where the model classes used for SQL INSERTs, are separate from the model classes used when you SELECT an existing row from the database.  Reason being that all my models are immutable...

- INSERT models have optional properties on them, e.g. for fields that the database will automatically populate during INSERT using default values / SQL TRIGGERs.
- SELECT models don't have any optional properties, there will always be a scalar value or `null` (but never `undefined`).

So some simple examples, let's say there's two SQL tables: `user` and `blog`, this means I have 4x separate models:

```js
class Insert_user {
    readonly id:string;
    readonly username:string;
    readonly joined_at?:string; // Optional because: SQL will set a default value of NOW() during INSERT

    constructor(props:Insert_user) { Object.assign(this, props); Object.freeze(this); }
}
class Select_user {
    readonly id:string;
    readonly username:string;
    readonly joined_at:string; // we know it will always be there when pulling an existing record out

    constructor(props:Select_user) { Object.assign(this, props); Object.freeze(this); }

}
class Insert_blog {
    readonly id:string;
    readonly blog_title:string;
    readonly view_count?:number; // Optional because: SQL will set a default value of 0 during INSERT

    constructor(props:Insert_blog) { Object.assign(this, props); Object.freeze(this); }
}
class Select_blog {
    readonly id:string;
    readonly blog_title:string;
    readonly view_count:number;  // we know it will always be there when pulling an existing record out

    constructor(props:Select_blog) { Object.assign(this, props); Object.freeze(this); }

}
```

I want to be able to write multiple functions that can receive the "Insert" models, but the typing system will know to return the corresponding "Select" model, based on the input.  e.g.

```js
type AnyInsertModel = Insert_user | Insert_blog;
type AnySelectModel = Select_user | Select_blog;

function takeAnInsertModelButReturnItsSelectModel(insertModel:AnyInsertModel) {
    // data from insert model is INSERTed into SQL database
    // after the INSERT is done, the data is then SELECTed from the 
    const selectModel = {/* data that we pulled using SELECT */} as Select_???;
}


/**
 * I want the type for the output variable below to be Select_user
 */
const selectedUser = takeAnInsertModelButReturnItsSelectModel(new Insert_user({id: 'd110ec70-9a16-4ad0-a73b-82e241a054eb', username: 'Neo'}));

/**
 * I want the type for the output variable below to be Select_blog
 */
const selectedBlog = takeAnInsertModelButReturnItsSelectModel(new Insert_blog({id: '2068bc9d-f19d-4043-a13a-6af4b2207be2', blog_title: 'I liek milk'}));
```

I want the types to be "converted" simply from function arguments, i.e. I don't want to have to give a redundant generic on every function call (generics are ok on the function definitions themselves though), seeing the argument is already typed to begin with.

***Looks like I might have solved it myself (answer below), keen to hear about any other approaches too though.***

Comment: It's quite possible that with some more structure in your empty example classes I could give you a solution that doesn't need conditional types, but right now they are all just... empty.  Could you add a skeleton of some structure there?  Empty classes in TypeScript [behave strangely](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) and don't make for good examples for that reason.

Comment: @jcalz - I've added some properties and the constructors into the 4x class definitions.  They're basically just used like interfaces.  I used classes so that I can easily get the class name at runtime.  But I am considering just using interfaces for everything later on, so keen for solutions that would work with both classes + interfaces.

Comment: Is there any *structural* difference between `Required<Insert_XYZ>` and `Select_XYZ`?  Is the only difference whether properties are optional?  If that's it then I would just use `Required` in my answer and not worry about naming the specific class (since types in TypeScript are structural, you don't need the *name* to be the same to refer to the same type)

Answer (score 0):

While trying a bunch of approaches while writing this, I came across ["conditional types"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) which appears to be exactly for this:

```js
type InsertToSelect<T extends AnyInsertModel> =
         T extends Insert_user ? Select_user :
         T extends Insert_blog ? Select_blog :
         never

function takeAnInsertModelButReturnItsSelectModel<InputGeneric extends AnyInsertModel>(insertArg: InputGeneric): InsertToSelect<InputGeneric> {
    const selectedModel = someCodeThatInsertsAndThenSelects();
    return selectedModel as InsertToSelect<InputGeneric>;
}
```

But keen to hear if there are any other approaches that would have worked?

Comment: Do you really want the output of `InsertToSelect` to be a string literal type?  Is `takeAnInsertModelButReturnItsSelectModel()` supposed to return literally the string `"Select_user"`?  Or is it supposed to return a value of type `Select_user`?  If its the latter then you should change `InsertToSelect<T>` to not have string literals in it

Comment: @jcalz - whoops, thanks for pointing that out.  Fixed now.